# Not sure about the interpretation of this residual plot

Tags: regression, residuals

I'm analyzing a residual plot  of the residuals vs the fitted values.

I'm not quite sure how to interpret this plot since there looks like there is a pattern and the average is not actually zero. There are diagonal straight parallel lines.

[image: Residual plot]

I'm working with several ordinal IV's.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your dependent/explained/left-hand-side/$y$-variable has only 5 categories. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. @MaartenBuis

Comment: If there is a pattern in your residual plot it means there is some underlying factor that affects the dependent variable that isn't being taken into account in your regression. If you find that variable and include it in your model the pattern should disappear

Comment: The average of the residuals is easily calculated with any decent software (looks like Stata in your case, but any software should support that).

Comment: What are your goals in fitting this model?

Comment: @cimentadaj so both the IV and DV are ordered?

Comment: @Underminer both the DV and IV are ordinal variables. The DV is a likert scale of 5 and de IV's are likert scales of 4, 4 and 10.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, I'm trying to predict the position of people in reducing or not income differences with perception of salary, household income and position in the left right scale. I'm just trying to see if the assumptions of the Multiple Regression Model are being met

Comment: If you told me an individual would be on the lowest Likert band, I would guess their residual was negative. This seems to be an exploitable bias.

Comment: The multivariate regression assumptions definitely are not being met, as evidenced by the strong change in distribution of the residuals from one end of the plot to the other (from positively to negatively skewed). This is a very clear indication that you should be using some form of generalized linear model or at least a nonlinear transformation of the dependent variable. The ordered logit or ordered probit model suggested by @Nick Cox would be a good start (and is implemented in Stata).

Answer (score 5):

You are using a Likert scale or similarly defined ordinal dependent (and independent) variable and modeling it in the same way as a continuous variable.  The debate of whether Likert scale can be modeled as a continuous numeric variable is a bit murky and can be summarized here:

http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/can-likert-scale-data-ever-be-continuous/

In practice, I tend to not have a problem with treating ordinal independent variables as numeric variables if there are at least five values and you are somewhat confident they are equally spaced on the spectrum of possible values -- that is, a difference between any two consecutive is approximately of equal magnitude.  This practice is not grounded in theory, but experience has shown me that results tend to not be badly biased.

If this work is intended to be published, I suggest you either carefully justify your decision to use this method or look into alternative methods.  EDIT:  As suggested by @NickCox in the comments, ordered logit (or probit) regression would be a suitable alternative to deal with the ordinal response variable.

One consequence of treating the variables as continuous is that the residual plot can appear as a series of parallel lines, as your plot shows.  This makes the typical pattern detection of the residual plot more difficult since the points clearly will not be randomly scattered.

As far as your plot is concerned, I believe it is acceptable.  There is no clear curvature of the plot, and no fanning (i.e. no heteroscedasticity).  They appear (to me) to form a roughly horizontal band if you take the density of points into account when forming the band.  I would suggest plotting the absolute value of the residuals to help assess heteroscedasticity further.

Comment: Ordered logit (probit) is an alternative: there is no obvious need to jump all the way to nonparametric.

Comment: How about the fact that the obvious omitted variable causes variance at the tails to be twice what it is in the middle? Not trying to be antagonistic, but if you don't see a problem with it I'm interested as to why.

Comment: @ssdecontrol How do you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @NickCox Ordered logit (probit) models are used to model ordered dependent variables.  The original poster has ordered independent variables.

Comment: @NickCox the deviations from the mean are bigger at the tails because of the "slant," hence heteroskedasticity. The existence of the slant means (to me) linear overprediction on the left and underprediction on the right. Or am I misinterpreting the plot? Mind you, I'm eyeballing the mean to be around zero

Comment: The slanting lines are for each distinct observed value. You have to average over them mentally (or otherwise, given the data) to see the underlying picture. I find it best not to try to read too much into the plot other than looking for general pattern and really obvious outliers. My guess is some of what else can be seen is a side-effect of skewness in the response.

Comment: @underminer Yes, but also a discrete response variable, as  can be inferred from the pattern; in any case that has been confirmed by the OP in comments.

Comment: @NickCox It appears the OP did, in fact, confirm a discrete response variable. Ordered logit (probit) should be included as an alternative to take into account the ordinal response variable. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @underminer Not a mistake on your part, as OP could helpfully have been clearer.

Comment: @NickCox I'm talking about the overall "slanted rectangle" shape. I'm not sure how to move this to chat but I don't want to clog up the comments here

Comment: @ssdecontrol Although all the points form a "slanted rectangle", the largest density fall in a more narrow horizontal band around 0.  That being said, there appears to be an overprediction to the left which is the main concern I see..

Comment: Tinkering with the linear model seems the lesser issue, as I would strongly prefer a model for ordinal responses.

Comment: Since you haven't described the scope of your experience, readers have no objective basis for deciding whether or not your experience might apply to their situations.  This answer therefore would be made considerably stronger by replacing the appeal to experience by a suggestion to conduct a test of linearity.